# JavaFX list like the library in the SceneBuilder

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I was trying to recreate the look of the Library-List within the SceneBuilder, but I don't have any idea, which element I need to take.

How can I recreate this list?

[image: Picture of the Library-List]

Comment: Is your question: how can you create a stack of expandable sections, each containing a set of buttons with an icon?

Comment: It's looks like a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html), with some style applied using CSS and probably a custom cell factory to add the graphics on the left. (And the `ListView` is used as the content for a [`TitledPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html).) Note that the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src) is freely available... (I haven't looked at it).

Comment: Start with Accordion then add ListViews like James_D suggest.

Comment: Thanks! I already have the Accordion, and with your tips i think i will get it. Furthermore the reminder about the source is a great idea.

Comment: Specifically you can see it [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src/ef68e38ec2422a66f71f3922b5aa83a5ece1aa84/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/library/LibraryPanelController.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) (`populateLibraryPanel()` method) - the list cell is defined [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src/ef68e38ec2422a66f71f3922b5aa83a5ece1aa84/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/library/LibraryListCell.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)...

Comment: and the style is defined by CSS which (I think) is [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src/ef68e38ec2422a66f71f3922b5aa83a5ece1aa84/src/main/resources/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/css/ThemeDark.css?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough draft using ControlsFx Awesome Fonts.

> Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication73 extends Application
{    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxapplication73.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Accordion prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ListView fx:id="lvOne" layoutX="-19.0" layoutY="-50.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 3">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.FontAwesome;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML ListView lvOne;

    ObservableList<CustomItem> listViewData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
        lvOne.setItems(listViewData);
        lvOne.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<CustomItem>, ListCell<CustomItem>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<CustomItem> call(ListView<CustomItem> listView)
            {
                return new ListViewCell();
            }
        });

        CustomItem ci = new CustomItem();        
        ci.setLabelGlyph(FontAwesome.Glyph.FLASH);
        ci.setString("entry one");
        listViewData.add(ci);

        CustomItem ci2 = new CustomItem();        
        ci2.setLabelGlyph(FontAwesome.Glyph.AMBULANCE);
        ci2.setString("entry two");
        listViewData.add(ci2);
    }    

}
```

> ListView Cell:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<CustomItem>
{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(CustomItem item, boolean empty)
    {         
       super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) 
        {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } 
        else 
        {
            Label label = item.getLabel();
            setGraphic(label);
        }       
    }
}
```

> CustomItem:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.FontAwesome;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.FontAwesome.Glyph;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class CustomItem
{
    private final Label label = new Label();

    public void setLabelGlyph(Glyph glyph)
    {
        FontAwesome fa = new FontAwesome();
        label.setGraphic(fa.create(glyph));
    }

    public void setString(String string)
    {
        label.setText(string);
    }

    public Label getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This needs updating! Now, I know that nodes should not be passed in `updateItem`. The   `updateItem` implementation here completely goes against cell virtualization.