# How to use FontAwesomeIconView in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, icons, font-awesome, desktop

Im working on a simple app on java using JavaFX, i wanted to create icones to add into table view but it doesnt work , im using FontAwesomeIconView , i'v already added the jar into my project ,
so here is what im doing in my code :

```
 FontAwesomeIconView deleteIcon = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.ICON_ANCHOR);
```

the given error :

```
The constructor FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon) is undefined
```

i saw this way of using icones on many exemples .

Thanks in advance .

***EDIT :***

[image]

Comment: I have noticed that people (I am people) run into many issues with `FontAwesome` because they don't use the correct jars. List your `POM`.

Comment: @Sedrick i have added a picture of my referenced libraries

Comment: You can also look into using `ControlsFX`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369243/javafx-list-like-the-library-in-the-scenebuilder/43372134#43372134

Comment: do i have to import jars for ControlsFX ?

Comment: Either one should work.

Comment: Can you repost your answer? i can't find it anymore ? Thank you

Comment: I removed it because it was for `Java9+` and it looks like you are using `Java8`.

Comment: I would suggest you use `ControlsFX`.

Comment: Ah i see ,Okey Thank you for help i'll try using it :) .